# JS redirect according to user agent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, redirect, user-agent

I'm sorry if that question is obvious to solve, but I don't know JavaScript yet but feels like it's the only way to implement what my clients need for their website.

I want to redirect users with specific browser to the specific simplified page once they visit homepage and keep this redirection work everytime they click on homepage button. Basically what I want is a 301 redirect based on user-agent. I've tried many times but all I've got was an infinte redirection loop or no result at all.

```
function get_ya_browser(){
var ua = navigator.userAgent;    
if (ua.search(/YaBrowser/) > 0) document.location.href='redirect-link.html';
return '';
}
```

How could I change this code to work? Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: If the user is already on the page `redirect-link.html`, you must of course not redirect there again then. So add a check for what the current URL is …?

Comment: Sorry, don't get it yet. Should I replace 'return ''' with something else?
How could I stop redirection?

Comment: No, you should add something to your _condition_.

Comment: Thank you. Is it right? `if (ua.search(/YaBrowser/) > 0 && document.URL.indexOf("redirect-link.html") >= 0) `

Answer (score 0):

Try -  document.location.replace ='redirect-link.html';
instead of  document.location.href ='redirect-link.html';

.location.replace() simulates a HTTP redirect
.location.href() simulates a mouseclick

Comment: Thank you. Should it be like this? 
`function get_ya_browser(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;    
    if (ua.search(/YaBrowser/) > 0 && document.URL.indexOf("redirect-link.html") >= 0) document.location.replace=('redirect-link.html');
    return '';
  }
`

Comment: Hm, no, this code is still not working. Looks like there's a trouble with something other than `document.location.replace`

Answer (score 0):

If the code was part of `redirect-link.html` && `ua.search(/YaBrowser/) !== -1`, you will get an infinite loop.

following code solved this problem:

```js
function get_ya_browser(){
   var ua = navigator.userAgent;    
   if (ua.search(/YaBrowser/) !== -1 && !location.href.includes('elbrus-m-zakaz.ru/home-page-windows-xp/')) {
      document.location.href='//elbrus-m-zakaz.ru/home-page-windows-xp/';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I feel stupid. It's not working for me. What could be wrong...

Comment: Could please paste the content of this page `redirect-link.html`

Comment: Yes, right. I want to set redirect from homepage https://elbrus-m-zakaz.ru/ to https://elbrus-m-zakaz.ru/home-page-windows-xp for specific browsers only, it's simplified page for older OS, let's call it this way.

Comment: Wow, updated the code.  Same page, different routes.

Comment: Nope, still not getting the result. Maybe there's something wrong with user-agent detection line?..

Comment: Maybe. [It does not work] or [It still an infinite loop]?  NOT WORK may caused by user-agent detection.

Comment: It's not working. When I refresh my page in this browser (with cleared cache after updating this code), it just refreshing, not redirect at all.
Which is strange, because when I've tried to detect this particular browser using this slug `/YaBrowser/`, it worked.

Comment: Here's the solution I've tried to detect if user uses Yandex Browser or not: https://codepen.io/AndrewHaze/pen/jGdKop In my case it has worked, so I used some parts of this code as far I understood it. (Not a coder at all)